# Proving that $\lim \limits_{x \to a^+} f(x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We have $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following property

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M |x - y|^{1/2}$$

for $x, y \in (a,b)$ and a constant $M$. Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to a^+} f(x)$ exists.

---

$f$ is uniformly continuous: fix $\epsilon > 0$, and take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon^2}{M^2}$.

Now, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that the $f(x)$ with $a < x < \delta$ differ by less than $\epsilon$. Thus it much approach some limit.

I believe my logic is correct, but I don't know how to make the argument more rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

You can't claim $f$ is uniformly continuous, given $f$ is continuous on an open interval $(a,b)$ (instead you would need the closed interval $[a,b]$). However, consider this. Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $(a,b)$ which converges to $a$. Then $|f(x_n) - f(x_m)| \le M|x_n - x_m|^{1/2} \to 0$ as $n,m\to \infty$. Hence $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$. By completeness of $\Bbb R$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$ exists. Let $L = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$. Let $y_n$ be another sequence in $(a,b)$ which converges to $a$. Then

$$|f(y_n) - L| \le |f(y_n) - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - L| \le M|x_n - y_n|^{1/2} + |f(x_n) - L| \to 0$$

since $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$ and $|f(x_n) - L| \to 0$. This proves $f(a_n) \to L$ for every sequence $(a_n)$ in $(a,b)$ which converges to $a$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x) = L$.

Comment: For the first sentence: Do you mean you can't in general, or are you saying that you can't even given the special property?

Comment: I mean you can't in general. You're essentially trying to *prove* $f$ is uniformly continuous. For the same argument shows that $\lim_{x\to b^{-}} f(x)$ exists. A continuous function on $(a,b)$ with finite one-sided limits at $a$ and $b$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: The stated domain of $f$ is $(a,b)$. It is uniformly continuous on its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just about every type of limit has an associate Cauchy criterion.

In the present example, it states that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)$ exists if, and only if, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta$ with the property that $$x,y \in (a, a+\delta) \implies |f(x) - f(y)| <\epsilon.$$

Comment: I was wondering if I could just say this, but it looks so similar to uniform continuity that I wasn't sure if this was that trivial. Is there a way to derive this Cauchy criterion from the standard definition of limit?

Comment: @Soke This is far from uniform continuity, pretty far indeed. Uniform continuity, non-rigorously, is when the position of $x,y$ doesn't matter and only the distance between them matters. Here, they have to be in a neighborhood of $a$ which makes it different from uniform continuity. Google Cauchy's Criterion, and you should get a good proof that a function has a limit if and only if it is cauchy.

Comment: @HasanSaad Well, I'm saying it's such an obvious corollary of uniform continuity. This is supposed to be a challenge problem.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood..

Comment: Well, the Cauchy criterion (once you know it for sequences) is pretty simple too. Select a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $(a,b)$ that decreases to $a$. The stated property implies that $\{f(x_k)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$,so that $f(x_k)$ converges to some limit $L$. Then  $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a^+$ because of your stated condition.